# Staggering posts in WordPress from two different categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am making a WordPress theme and would like to stagger posts by category in a slider, and on the blog page.

So far this is what I have:

```
$arg1 = array('category_name' => 'Photographs' );
$arg2 = array('category_name' => 'Quotes' );
$myposts1 = get_posts( $arg1 );
$myposts2 = get_posts( $arg2 );
```

I want to the loop output to be something like this:

```
<article>
    Photographs
</article>
<article>
    Quotes
</article>
<article>
    Photographs
</article>
<article>
    Quotes
</article>
ect..
```

I can manage the output of the loop once I get the structure setup.  I know how to add the following tags inside of the loop, I just can't figure out how to set up the initial structure.

```
<?php
    the_title();
    the_permalink();
    the_post_thumbnail();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-order to use tempalte tags, you have to loop on WordPress standard loop.
I have added customizer option in the slider to choose category and had this following query on the tempaltes:

```
$st_portfolio_id = get_theme_mod( 'styledstore_slider_category' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'terms'    => $st_portfolio_id
            ),
        )
    ) ); ?>
```

The following code was extracted from WordPress Free themes called [Styled Store.](https://wordpress.org/themes/styled-store/)

Hope this helps

Comment: <?php
        $quotes = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
        $photographs = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');

        $length1 = count($quotes);
        $length2 = count($photographs);

        if($length1 <= $length2){
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length1; $i++) {
                print $quotes[$i];
                print $photographs[$i];
            }
        }else{
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length2; $i++) {
                print $quotes[$i];
                print $photographs[$i];
            }
        }
    ?>

Comment: I came up with the above method.  Would that be acceptable for WordPress?